# Calling stored procedure in postgresql from sqlalchemy

Tags: postgresql, python-2.7, sqlalchemy

I'm using sqlalchemy for python ORM , and I want to call a stored procedure which exists in postgresql. I can't find useful tutorials ,please tell me how to code.

Thank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know about any special classes SQLAlchemy provides for calling a procedure.

However you can always use simple select like:

```
SELECT * FROM proc(4,2);
```

Comment: This might be because what you have advised is deprecated now but following this I now get

ProgrammingError: (psycopg2.errors.WrongObjectType) my_database.my_sp() is a procedure
LINE 1: select * from my_database.my_sp...
                      ^
HINT:  To call a procedure, use CALL.

[SQL: select * from my_database.my_sp();]
(Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/f405)

Answer (score 2):

Using `execute()` on `Connection`or `Engine` object, like:

```
result = conn.execute('SELECT procname(?,?)', 1, 2).fetchall()
```

Take a look at [SQLAlchemy documentation](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_8/core/connections.html) for more info.